# HTML + CSS fails on center alignment of mat-icon

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-datatable

Problem: my generated columns doesn't center align my mat-icon.
What am I missing?

On ngFor my datatable columns are generated dynamically, but no one's align correctly.

Inside my DIV there's a mat-icon that's (by default) apply for left  alignment.

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="let col of colunas">
        <ngx-datatable-column [name]="col.ds_titulo_coluna" *ngIf="col.fl_exibe_coluna">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <div *ngIf="row[col.id] === 'pend'">
                    <div class="v-align-middle">
                        <mat-icon class="warning">info</mat-icon>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="row[col.id] === 'rep'">
                    <div class="v-align-middle">
                        <mat-icon class="red-fg">report_off</mat-icon>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="row[col.id] === 'ok'">
                    <div class="v-align-middle">
                        <mat-icon class="green-fg">check_circle</mat-icon>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="row[col.id] === 'ag'">
                    <div class="v-align-middle">
                        <mat-icon class="orange-fg">schedule</mat-icon>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
    </div>
```

SCSS Code:

```
.ngx-datatable-column.text-center
{
   display: flex !important;
   align-items: center !important;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.warning{
   color: #dec71b;
}

.v-align-middle { 
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Result of code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xywTG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.v-align-middle` CSS rules as per below. Hope this will be worked for you.

```
.v-align-middle { 
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: sad.. same result :(

Comment: apply mat-icon { display: inline-flex; } in css stylesheet and let me know the result.

Comment: same result :\ ... if you need more informations or prints, let me know.. thanks in advice

Comment: Yes, need a live code snippet. Could you recreate it using stackbkitz or any other tool?